# Align 2 sections next to each other in responsive

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, css-float

[image: Screen Shot]

I want to align 2 sections next to each other. One has text(heading) and the text will be changing in length. one more section has a image.

My issue is when i make the screen size smaller, the second section is coming down.

Tried display:table-row; display:table; display:table-cell; nothing helps. the second div still comes down.

Please Help.

-Thanks in advance.

This is my code:
HTML

```
<h2><span>BE PREPARED  PREPARED</span><img src="http://localhost/safesteps/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/before_bg_r.png" alt="before_bg_r"/></h2>
```

CSS

```
.inner_berfore h2{
    display:table-row;
    border-top: 4px solid #767676;
    position: relative; 
    float:left;
    width:98%;
}
.inner_berfore h2 span{
    background:#767676;
    display:table-cell;
    font-family: 'arial-black';
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-left:16px;
    font-size:22px;
    line-height:40px;
    color:#FFF; 
    float:left;
}
.inner_berfore h2 img{
    display:table-cell;
    float:left;
    height:40px;
}
```

Comment: did you tried display:inline-block and giving width:49% to both?

Comment: I cannot specify width because the header text is changing each time.

Example:
WHEN THERE IS A FLOOD WARNING
<br/>
DURING

Comment: You can assign width in % and that will solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For static Text:
Try : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/anK6u/6/

```
div{display:inline-block;width:49%;vertical-align:top;}
div img{max-width:100%}
```

HTML:

```
<div>Text</div>
<div><img src="src" /></div>
```

you can assign different width as per your design

For dynamic text:

http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/anK6u/8/

CSS:

```
.table{display:table;}
.table div{display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;}
.table div img{max-width:100%}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
        <div>Hellodfgsdfgsdfghsdfhsdfhdsfhdfhdsfhsdfhsdh</div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://asia.olympus-imaging.com/products/dslr/e520/sample/images/sample_03.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Its not working!!
The header text is changing each time. If the text is small like"DURING" there is too much gray space left out and if the text is long like" WHEN THERE IS A FLOOD WARNING" the text is coming in two lines!!
Please help. Need to deliver this in an hour!!

Comment: Hey Thanks it helped. But the image is cutting in right. What to do about that?

Comment: modify max-width of img as per your needs. Or just give padding to the image container. If it works for you, you can accept it as answer then